# Image slider using div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem in image slider, in which i successfully added image and its sliding fine but while sliding both left and right end is extending a bit i don't know where i went wrong, this is happening in [in this link](http://www.crafart.com/crafartweb/)

And i have also added my jsp code

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 1 2 1 15;">
<div style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 4px;background-color:#FFFFFF;" id="productFieldsTabs">
        <li class="active" id="Bestseller"><a href="#Best-seller">BESTSELLER</a></li>
        <li id="Bestsoldproduct"><a href="#BestsoldProduct">BESTSOLDPRODUCT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent;">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Best-seller">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="carousel slide article-slide carousel-example-product" data-ride="carousel" style="padding: 0px;">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 item active">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="thumbnail product-box">
                                <img src="${context}/resources/img/product2/aprons-potholders.jpg" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="thumbnail product-box">
                                <img src="${context}/resources/img/product2/baking-dishes.jpg" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="thumbnail product-box">
                                <img src="${context}/resources/img/product2/canister.jpg" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-product1" role="presentation" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span
                    class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-product1" role="presentation" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above is a part for one image slider, I am getting all slider with above problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're seeing? I looked at your site and the sliders seem to be moving smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I noticed is that you are using several "row" classes without the "col" classes to make up for the negative margin.

That is not how the Bootstrap grid system works, and will cause the padding and margin of the entire page to have issues.

If you want to use a row, and still want the content to extend 100%, I would do something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```